# Access AppWidget even phone is in lock-screen

Tags: android, service, lockscreen, android-appwidget

I am building an android application that when the AppWidget is pressed a number of times, it will send an SMS. The application will run as service, and if the AppWidget is pressed a number of times it will send an SMS alert. Is there any way that the AppWidget can still be use even if the phone is in lock-screen?

Answer (score 0):

According docs it is possible for Android 4.2.
You should have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen)

For other versions, i am not sure but i think it's possible for some constructor layers

Answer (score 0):

In the widgets widget_info.xml file under res/xml you can add the following line of code:

```
android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"
```

This will allow your widget to be placed on the lock screen and home screen.